# How to design the view and give rotationEffect for server images in swiftui?

Tags: swift, swiftui

This is what I want this view design for static images:

[image: this is what I want this view design for static images]

I want to design a view which have rotation effect each view have different degree rotation from

```
[-10,10,0]
```

this array and set to the images. images comes from Api.

this is my Approach

```
struct Stacks: View{
    @State var rotate: [Int] = [-10, 10, 0]
    @State var index: Int = -1
    @StateObject var list = StacksViewModel()
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
        ForEach(list.datas, id: \.id){ item in
               ZStack{
                ForEach(item.stack_book_link, id: \.id){ images in
                    
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: images.book_url))
.frame(width: 125, height: 135)
.rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(rotate[ self.index + 1])))  
                    }
                }
                
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            list.getStacksData()
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Please update your code to make it a [mcve]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> **Try this approach** and this is main View which you want to show.

```
struct Stacks: View{
     @State var rotate: [Int] = [-20, 20, 0]
           @State var index: Int = -1
           @StateObject var list = StacksViewModel()
           
           var body: some View{
               VStack(spacing: 35){
                   ForEach(list.datas, id: \.id) { item in
                       ZStack{
                           ForEach(item.stack_book_link.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                               AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.stack_book_link[index].book_url)){ img in
                                   img.resizable().frame(width: 125, height: 155)
                                       .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(rotate[ index])))
                                       .shadow(radius: 5)
                               }placeholder: {
                                   Image("u").resizable().frame(width: 125, height: 155).rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(rotate[ index])))
                                       .shadow(radius: 5)
                               }
    
                           }
                       }
                   }
               }
               .onAppear{
                   list.getStacksData()
               }
           } 
    }
```

> This is ViewModel.

```
class StacksViewModel: ObservableObject{
   
    @Published var datas = [StacksDatum]()
    @Published var image: [String] = []
   
    func getStacksData() {
        
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        guard let token = defaults.string(forKey: "access_token") else {
            return
        }
        //Give authentication(StacksService()) and then fetching data 
        StacksService().getStacksData(token: token){ (result) in
            switch result {
                case .success(let results):
                    DispatchQueue.main.async {
                        self.datas = results.studentStacks.data
                        
                        for data in self.datas {
                            for imgdata in data.stack_book_link{
                                self.image.append(imgdata.book_url)
                            }
                            
                        }
                        print(self.datas)
                    }
                case .failure(let error):
                    print(error.localizedDescription)
            }
        }
    }
      
}
```

> In my side it shows very correctly. my system xcode 14.1 and ios 15. StacksService() is a class and it gives authentication that the user is authenticate or not.

Answer (score 0):

Iterating through `item.stackBookLink.indices` you can do it like this:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    @State var rotate: [Int] = [-10, 10, 0]
    @State var index: Int = -1
    @StateObject var list = StacksViewModel()
    
    var body: some View{
        VStack{
            ForEach(list.datas, id: \.id) { item in                
                ZStack{                
                    ForEach(item.stackBookLink.indices, id: \.self) { index in
                        AsyncImage(url: URL(string: item.stackBookLink[index].bookUrl))
                        
                            .frame(width: 125, height: 135)
                            .rotationEffect(Angle(degrees: Double(rotate[ index])))
                            .shadow(radius: 5)
                    }
                }                
            }
        }
        .onAppear{
            list.getStacksData()
        }
    }
}


struct BookLink: Identifiable {
    let id = UUID()
    let bookUrl: String
}

struct Item {
    let id = UUID()
    let stackBookLink: [BookLink]
}

class StacksViewModel: ObservableObject {
    
    
    @Published var datas: [Item] = []
    
    func getStacksData() {
        datas = [Item(stackBookLink: [BookLink(bookUrl: "https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
                                          BookLink(bookUrl: "https://picsum.photos/200/300"),
                                          BookLink(bookUrl: "https://picsum.photos/200/300")])]
    }
}
```

[image]

Also, note that variable names in Swift are written using `lowerCamelCase`, not `snake_case`